# Font-face не работает

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, почему не работает шрифт?

css:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: ntw;
    src: url('../fonts/dominojack.otf') format('otf');
}

h1.newfont {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: ntw;
}
```

html:

```
<div>
<h1 class="ntw">Remotion server</h1>
```

Пути правильные, файлы валидные. 
Css подключается к странице корректно (работаю с asp.net mvc, подключаю через бандлы, в коде страницы css добавляются корректно). Ничего не работает, даже `text-align: center` не применяется

Всё заработало. Поменял h1.newfont на .newfont

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в  `@font-face`, возможно путь не правильно прописан, возможно формат не подходящий.

Как пример подключения шрифта:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ntw;
    src: url('path-to-font/dominojack.otf') format('otf');
    src: url('path-to-font/dominojack.otf') format('eot');
    src: url('path-to-font/dominojack.ttf') format('ttf') format("truetype");        
    src: url('path-to-font/dominojack.otf') format('woff') format("woff");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Путь правильный.
Скачивал с сайта с бесплатными шрифтами, да и винда нормально определяет файл.

Comment: Как выше сказал - попробовал другой шрифт с другим расширением, тоже не работает

Answer (score 1):

А вот и решение :)
**Это вставьте в ваш CSS**

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'dominojack';
    src: url('../fonts/dominojack.otf') format('otf');
}
.newfont h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'dominojack';
}
```

**А это в HTML**

```
<div class="newfont">
    <h1>Remotion server</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё еще не работает! Я даже другой шрифт попробовал вообще с другим расширением

Comment: Где у вас расположен файл с вашим шрифтом?

Comment: Каталог проекта/fonts/

Comment: может вы путь от файла css неправильно указали.

Comment: Указал правильно. В код страницы то css файл добавляется

Comment: Я так и не понял у вас отдельный файл со стилями, или вы стили в html прописываете?

Comment: Отдельный файл. Добавляется, в смысле когда в браузере тестирую, то в коде страницы присутствует
<link href="/Content/fontstyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Уберите / перед Content/fontstyles.css

Comment: Там всё правильно, я вас уверяю. Скорее всего, это какой то баг visual studio либо у меня что-то с синтаксисом css